# only one Column was populated in my Tableview

Tags: mysql, javafx

i'm populating my tableview from mysql database but only the column ID is the only one that's populated.

my main:

```
        public void populate() throws Exception{

     ObservableList<userdata1> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

     tableView();

     try{   
            String query = "select * from members";        
           ps = new Connect().connectDatabase1();
           rs = ps.executeQuery(query);         
            while(rs.next()){             
            data.add(new userdata1(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getInt(3)));            
           tblView.setItems(data);   
           }


       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.print("asdqweasd");

       }
}


        public void tableView()throws Exception{            
        tblView.getItems().clear();        
        tblView.getColumns().clear();   
        rs = ps.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members");      
        ObservableList<userdata1> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();       
        TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn("ID");    
        column1.setMinWidth(85);     
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));        
         TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn("Name");
        column2.setMinWidth(565);
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory<>("comp_name"));   
        TableColumn column3 = new TableColumn("STATUS");    
        column3.setMinWidth(123);     
        column3.setCellValueFactory(new javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory<>("mem_status")); 



        tblView.getColumns().addAll(column1,column2,column3);     

    }
```

my userdata1:

```
public class userdata1 {
    public SimpleIntegerProperty ID;
     public SimpleStringProperty comp_name;
     public SimpleIntegerProperty mem_status;

    public userdata1(Integer id, String comp_name, Integer mem_status){
           this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
           this.comp_name = new SimpleStringProperty(comp_name);
           this.mem_status = new SimpleIntegerProperty(mem_status);

       }
    public Integer getID() {
            return ID.get();
        }  

          public String getcomp_name(){
             return comp_name.get();
        }

        public Integer getmem_status() {
            return mem_status.get();
        }


        public void setID(Integer id) {

            this.ID.set(id);
        }

        public void setcomp_name(String comp_name ) {
           this.comp_name.set(comp_name);
        }

        public void setmem_status(Integer mem_status) {

            this.mem_status.set(mem_status);
        }
}
```

the data mem_status and comp_name is not populating their respective columns

Answer (score 0):

As `UserData1` already contains `Properties`, you can set the according `Property` to the `cellValueFactory`:

```
public class UserData1 {
    private StringProperty comp_name;
    //additional fields, getters and setters  

    public StringProperty comp_nameProperty() {
        return comp_name;
    }
}


setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().comp_nameProperty());
```

If you want to stick to the `PropertyValueFactory` you have to access the fields according to the CamelCase convention:

```
column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("comp_name"));


public class UserData1 {
   //...
   public String getComp_name(){
             return comp_name.get();
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. the CamelCase convention in my getter is the only problem.. :)) i really appreciate your answer.. thankyou very much :)

Comment: i just thought that using underscore in my getComp_Name will not be the problem in getter but it seems that the underscore was read as connector to any word and make it as one.. (correct me if im wrong in using such terms) so changing the getComp_Name to getComp_name is the solution for this problem. tnx again folks